# How to setup Stored Procedure to sort properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure where the end goal is to order the data by '**Parcel_ID**', when the report runs, the data is not actually ordered by the parcel_id as seen in the photo. Where am I going wrong in the syntax? The desired result is that it match the database like this: [image]

[image]

```
 string sqlWhere = "";

            if (startDate != null && endDate != null)
                sqlWhere = " AND Posting_Date BETWEEN '" + startDate + "' AND '" + endDate + "'";

            string sqlStatement = "";
            sqlStatement = @"select parcel_id, 
                            Ownership_sequence, 
                            sum(tax) as Tax, 
                            Sum(Discount) as Discount, 
                            Sum(penalty) as Penalty, 
                            Sum(Additional_Penalty) as Additional_Penalty 

                                INTO temp_AttorneyFeesWithSuit
                                from trans where ownership_id in (select ownership_id from cownership_CollectionCodes 
                                where is_suit = 1 and year_to <= 2019) " + sqlWhere 
             + @"group by parcel_id, ownership_sequence
                                Having sum(Additional_Penalty) > 0
                                order by Parcel_ID";



            //INSERT INTO temp_AttorneyFeesWithSuit
            sqlAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlStatement, sqlWhere);
```

Comment: A table, even your temp table, has NO inherent ordering. You can insert in any order you wish and the data will be stored to disk in an order that the database feels is best for storage and retrieval speeds; this is the nature of an RDBMS. If you want ordered data from your temp table, then add an `ORDER BY` clause to your select statement like `SELECT * FROM temp_AttorneyFeesWithSuit ORDER BY parcel_id;`. You may also notice that this means your `ORDER BY` in your procedure is superfluous and can be removed.

Comment: @JNevill  You should just put that comment as an answer, as it is the correct answer here.

Comment: @iamdave I think closing as a duplicate would be more appropriate since this gets asked pretty frequently. I was unable to find a highly upvoted canonical answer, but the one I've flagged in the `close` dialog should suffice.